# Get run id after triggering a github workflow dispatch event

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

I am triggering a workflow run via github's rest api. But github doesn't send any data in the response body (204).
How do i get the run id of the trigger request made?
I know about the `getRunsList` api, which would return runs for a workflow id, then i can get the latest run, but this can cause issues when two requests are submitted at almost the same time.

Comment: A github support ticket for this issue was closed with response: "This is not currently supported. Github has this in their internal feature list. Some workaround needs to be followed, but will be buggy." For workaround please find the accepted answer below.

Comment: See also this [discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9752) in the GitHub community.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not currently possible to get the run_id associated to the dispatch API call in the dispatch response itself, but there is a way to find this out if you can edit your worflow file a little.

You need to dispatch the workflow with an `input` like this:

```sh
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/workflows/$WORKFLOW/dispatches" -s \
     -H "Authorization: Token $TOKEN" \
     -d '{
        "ref":"master",
        "inputs":{
            "id":"12345678"
        }
    }'
```

Also edit your workflow yaml file with an optionnal `input` (named `id` here). Also, place it as the first job, a job which has a single step with the same name as the input `id` value (this is how we will get the id back using the API!):

```yaml
name: ID Example

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      id:
        description: 'run identifier'
        required: false
jobs:
  id:
    name: Workflow ID Provider
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: ${{github.event.inputs.id}}
        run: echo run identifier ${{ inputs.id }}
```

The trick here is to use `name: ${{github.event.inputs.id}}`

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs

Then the flow is the following:

- run the dispatch API call along with the `input` named `id` in this case with a random value

  ```
  POST https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/workflows/$WORKFLOW/dispatches
  ```
- in a loop get the runs that have been created since now minus 5 minutes (the delta is to avoid any issue with timings):

  ```
  GET https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/runs?created=>$run_date_filter
  ```

[example](https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping/actions/runs?created=%3E2021-10-07T23:46:00)

- in the run API response, you will get a `jobs_url` that you will call:

  ```
  GET https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/runs/[RUN_ID]/jobs
  ```
- the job API call above returns the list of jobs, as you have declared the `id` jobs as 1st job it will be in first position. It also gives you the `steps` with the `name` of the steps. Something like this:

```json
{
  "id": 3840520726,
  "run_id": 1321007088,
  "run_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/runs/1321007088",
  "run_attempt": 1,
  "node_id": "CR_kwDOEi1ZxM7k6bIW",
  "head_sha": "4687a9bb5090b0aadddb69cc335b7d9e80a1601d",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/jobs/3840520726",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/$OWNER/$REPO/runs/3840520726",
  "status": "completed",
  "conclusion": "success",
  "started_at": "2021-10-08T15:54:40Z",
  "completed_at": "2021-10-08T15:54:43Z",
  "name": "Hello world",
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "Set up job",
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "number": 1,
      "started_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:40.000+02:00",
      "completed_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:42.000+02:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "12345678", <=============== HERE
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "number": 2,
      "started_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:42.000+02:00",
      "completed_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:43.000+02:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "Complete job",
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "number": 3,
      "started_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:43.000+02:00",
      "completed_at": "2021-10-08T17:54:43.000+02:00"
    }
  ],
  "check_run_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/check-runs/3840520726",
  "labels": [
    "ubuntu-latest"
  ],
  "runner_id": 1,
  "runner_name": "Hosted Agent",
  "runner_group_id": 2,
  "runner_group_name": "GitHub Actions"
}
```

The `name` of the `id` step is returning your input value, so you can safely confirm that it is this run that was triggered by your dispatch call

Here is an implementation of this flow in [python](/questions/tagged/python), it will return the workflow run id:

```py
import random
import string
import datetime
import requests
import time

# edit the following variables
owner = "YOUR_ORG" 
repo = "YOUR_REPO"
workflow = "dispatch.yaml"
token = "YOUR_TOKEN"

authHeader = { "Authorization": f"Token {token}" }

# generate a random id
run_identifier = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=15))
# filter runs that were created after this date minus 5 minutes
delta_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
run_date_filter = (datetime.datetime.utcnow()-delta_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") 

r = requests.post(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow}/dispatches",
    headers= authHeader,
    json= {
        "ref":"master",
        "inputs":{
            "id": run_identifier
        }
    })

print(f"dispatch workflow status: {r.status_code} | workflow identifier: {run_identifier}")
workflow_id = ""

while workflow_id == "":
        
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs?created=%3E{run_date_filter}",
        headers = authHeader)
    runs = r.json()["workflow_runs"]

    if len(runs) > 0:
        for workflow in runs:
            jobs_url = workflow["jobs_url"]
            print(f"get jobs_url {jobs_url}")

            r = requests.get(jobs_url, headers= authHeader)
            
            jobs = r.json()["jobs"]
            if len(jobs) > 0:
                # we only take the first job, edit this if you need multiple jobs
                job = jobs[0]
                steps = job["steps"]
                if len(steps) >= 2:
                    second_step = steps[1] # if you have position the run_identifier step at 1st position
                    if second_step["name"] == run_identifier:
                        workflow_id = job["run_id"]
                else:
                    print("waiting for steps to be executed...")
                    time.sleep(3)
            else:
                print("waiting for jobs to popup...")
                time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("waiting for workflows to popup...")
        time.sleep(3)

print(f"workflow_id: {workflow_id}")
```

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/f1b0c06f0d19ca3bee832e786e495ff6)

Sample output

```
$ python3 github_action_dispatch_runid.py
dispatch workflow status: 204 | workflow identifier: Z7YPF6DD1YP2PTM
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321475221/jobs
waiting for steps to be executed...
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321475221/jobs
waiting for steps to be executed...
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321475221/jobs
waiting for steps to be executed...
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321475221/jobs
get jobs_url https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/1321463229/jobs
workflow_id: 1321475221
```

It would have been easier if there was a way to retrieve the workflow inputs via API but there is no way to do this at this moment

Note that in the worflow file, I use `${{github.event.inputs.id}}` because `${{inputs.id}}` doesn't work. It seems `inputs` is not being evaluated when we use it as the step name

Comment: Thanks for this solutions, I mention some consideration for the steps mentioned above. I had some problems related to the steps not being listed in the rest API response if the workflow is queued and not being processed yet, which I could solve checking the workflow run state and fetching that workflow run data again until the state has changed. Additionally the job steps will appear only if they were executed, pending steps will not be listed, causing some errors if it's in the "Set up job" step before setting our custom id. I've applied same solution to retry until it has at least 2 steps

Answer (score 2):

Get WORKFLOWID

```
gh workflow list --repo <repo-name>
```

Trigger workflow of type workflow_dispatch

```
gh workflow run $WORKFLOWID --repo <repo-name>
```

It **doesnot** return the run-id which is required get the status of execution

Get latest run-id WORKFLOW_RUNID

```
gh run list -w $WORKFLOWID --repo <repo> -L 1 --json databaseId | jq '.[]| .databaseId'
```

Get workflow run details

```
gh run view --repo <repo> $WORKFLOW_RUNID
```

This is workaround that we do. It is not perfect, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

inspired by the comment above, made a /bin/bash script which gets your $run_id

```
name: ID Example

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      id:
        description: 'run identifier'
        required: false
jobs:
  id:
    name: Workflow ID Provider
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: ${{github.event.inputs.id}}
        run: echo run identifier ${{ inputs.id }}
```

workflow_id= generates a random 8 digit number 
now, later, date_filter= use for time filter, now - 5 minutes \

- generates a random ID
- POST job and trigger workflow
- GET action/runs descending and gets first .workflow_run[].id
- keeps looping until script matches random ID from step 1
- echo run_id

```
TOKEN="" \
GH_USER="" \
REPO="" \
REF=""
WORKFLOW_ID=$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 8) \
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") \
LATER=$(date -d "-5 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") \
DATE_FILTER=$(echo "$NOW-$LATER") \
JSON=$(cat <<-EOF
{"ref":"$REF","inputs":{"id":"$WORKFLOW_ID"}}
EOF
) && \

curl -s \
-X POST \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
"https://api.github.com/repos/$GH_USER/$REPO/actions/workflows/main.yml/dispatches" \
-d $JSON && \

INFO="null" \
COUNT=1 \
ATTEMPTS=10 && \
until [[ $CHECK -eq $WORKFLOW_ID ]] || [[ $COUNT -eq $ATTEMPTS ]];do
echo -e "$(( COUNT++ ))..."
INFO=$(curl -s \
-X GET \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
"https://api.github.com/repos/$GH_USER/$REPO/actions/runs?created:<$DATE_FILTER" | jq -r '.workflow_runs[].id' | grep -m1 "")

CHECK=$(curl -s \
-X GET \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
"https://api.github.com/repos/$GH_USER/$REPO/actions/runs/$INFO/jobs" | jq -r '.jobs[].steps[].name' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*')
sleep 5s
done

echo "Your run_id is $CHECK"
```

output:

```
1...
2...
3...
Your run_id is 67530050
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [convictional/trigger-workflow-and-wait](https://github.com/convictional/trigger-workflow-and-wait) action:

```yaml
- name: Example
  uses: convictional/trigger-workflow-and-wait@v1.6.5
  with:
    owner: my-org
    repo: other-repo
    workflow_file_name: other-workflow.yaml
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
    client_payload: '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'
```

This takes care of waiting for the other job and returning a success or failure according to whether the other workflow succeeded or failed. It does so in a robust way that handles multiple runs being triggered at almost the same time.

Comment: This is not robust. If the case of a matrix job using this action to run a workflow with different input options you'll get the typical racy results that GitHub's API forces us to have. There's nothing that _actually_ ties a workflow dispatch to a run id in this action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a reliable way to get the run ID after dispatching a workflow, check out the [return-dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/return-dispatch) GitHub Action. It simplifies the process and provides a straightforward solution.

simple usage-

```
- name: Dispatch an action and get the run ID
    uses: codex-/return-dispatch@v1
    id: return_dispatch
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }} # Note this is NOT GITHUB_TOKEN but a PAT
      ref:  githubActions_iOS/build # or refs/heads/target_branch
      repo: feature
      owner: mr-x
      workflow: shared.yml
      workflow_inputs: '{ "distinct_id": "123" }' # Optional
      workflow_timeout_seconds: 120 # Default: 300
```

next you can read the run_id

```
- name: Use the output run ID
  run: echo ${{steps.return_dispatch.outputs.run_id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Affilitiation**: I acknowledge that I am a major contributor to this GitHub Action.

[`lasith-kg/dispatch-workflow@v1`](https://github.com/lasith-kg/dispatch-workflow) is a GitHub Action that dispatches workflows either using `repository_dispatch` or `workflow_dispatch` event and has an optional flag `discover: true`. When this flag is enabled, it injects a **unique UUID** into the Workflow Run Name so that it can be correlated to the initial dispatch event. Once the workflow is discovered, the **Run ID** and **Run URL** is available from the step outputs.

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: lasith-kg/dispatch-workflow@v1
    id: dispatch-with-discovery
    name: "Dispatch Workflow With Discovery"
    with:
      dispacth-method: workflow_dispatch | repository_dispatch
      ...
      discover: true
  - id: echo-run-id-url
    name: "Echo Run ID and Run URL"
    run: |
      echo "${{ steps.dispatch-with-discovery.outputs.run-id }}"
      echo "${{ steps.dispatch-with-discovery.outputs.run-url }}"
```

Naturally, the receiving workflow needs to be modified to intercept this UUID in the `run-name`

##### `workflow_dispatch`

```yaml
name: Receiving Workflow
run-name: Receiving Workflow [${{ inputs.distinct_id && inputs.distinct_id || 'N/A' }}]

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      distinct_id:
        description: 'Distinct ID'
        required: false
```

##### `repository_dispatch`

```yaml
name: Receiving Workflow
run-name: >
  Receiving Workflow [${{
    github.event.client_payload.distinct_id &&
    github.event.client_payload.distinct_id || 'N/A' }}]

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - deploy
```

Answer (score -1):

the whole idea is to know which run was dispatched, when id was suggested to use on dispatch, this id is expected to be found in the response of the GET call to this url "actions/runs" so now user is able to identify the proper run to monitor. The injected id is not part of the response, so extracting another url to find your id is not helpful since this is the point where id needed to identify the run for monitoring